Reach the point WHERE or WHEN...?
I almost memorize "reach the point where" as a fixed expression but I came across a sentence

"We had reached the point when there was no money left." (from Oxford Dictionary)

and there are also other sentences such as:

The project is at a point where the end is in sight.
I've reached the point where I'm about ready to retire.
(the two sentences didn't come from authority dictionary but they are indeed found in websites and proved correct in Chinese English exams)

I was confused and I thought that I could replace "point" with "moment" or "stage". Then both where and when can do. But it turns out that there will be only one correct choice. So I am expecting maybe someone could explain the difference. Which is correct?

Because a point is a metaphoric spatial reference to "a point in time", we're far more likely to reflect that with spatial where rather than temporal when. But the less common form certainly occurs, and it would be pointless pedantry to complain about it here.


I was confused and I thought that I could replace "point" with "moment" or "stage".

You can. "a point" can be a place in space or time.
OED Point (n.)

I. Senses relating to a small, discrete unit, location, measure, etc.
(corresponding broadly to French point: see the etymology).
I.i. Something having position in space, time, succession, degree,
order, etc.
I.i.1. A location in time; a moment, juncture, or stage.
I.i.1.b. A moment or instant considered in terms of its position in
time rather than its duration; the precise time at which something
happens; a particular stage in the course of a process over time.

For that reason "where" = "at which point" works for space and time, but "when" = "at which time" only works for time.
and we need to consider:

P.3. to the (also a) point where: to a situation, condition, extent,
etc., such that.
2009 My generation of Catholics have paid, prayed and obeyed, but you
get to a point where you've had it. New York Times (National edition)
6 January a1/1

in which it is impossible to distinguish if the speaker is referrencing a time or a place.

Thanks. Maybe it's a fact that most of people won't convey very specific information. Of course they don't need to.

Please don't 'accept' answers to questions closed as duplicates, Molly. It adds a layer of confusion when visitors are conducting searches.
